# In this case how the parameters pass

Tags: oracle, procedure

I have a procedure in oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE ReportCalculate
  (
        param_acTypeId in NUMBER
)
  AS 
  sqlstr VARCHAR2(500);
  result NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    sqlstr:='select count(1) from table1 where 1=1 and AC_TYPE_LEVEL1_ID=:acTypeId';
    execute immediate sqlstr into result using param_acTypeId;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(result);
  END;
```

But sometimes I would like to query all the data, sql looks like this 
`select count (1) from table1 where 1 = 1 and AC_TYPE_LEVEL1_ID = AC_TYPE_LEVEL1_ID`, 
then how should the parameters pass, or param_acTypeId should have any default value? Is it only in the stitching sql when to judge it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical method would be to accept `NULL` as meaning "all":

```
sqlstr := 'select count(1) from table1 where AC_TYPE_LEVEL1_ID = :acTypeId or :acTypeId is null';
```

I should note that this version precludes the use of indexes.  If performance is an issue, then use two queries:

```
if param_acTypeId is null then
    sqlstr := 'select count(1) from table1';
    execute immediate sqlstr into result;
else 
    sqlstr := 'select count(1) from table1 where AC_TYPE_LEVEL1_ID = :acTypeId';
    execute immediate sqlstr into result using param_acTypeId;
end if;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need dynamic SQL. If you pass in `NULL` then it will count all rows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ReportCalculate (
  param_acTypeId in NUMBER
)
AS 
  result NUMBER;
BEGIN
  select count(1)
  into   result
  from   table1
  where  ( param_acTypeId IS NULL OR AC_TYPE_LEVEL1_ID = param_acTypeId );

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(result);
END;
```